# No "privileges" link on meta site user profile card

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign, meta, privileges

There's no *privileges* link on the user dropdown card on meta sites:

> #### Main site:
>
> [image: Profile card dropdown with privileges link]
>
> #### Meta site:
>
> [image: Profile card dropdown without privileges link]

[`/privileges`](/privileges) on meta redirects to the main site's `/privileges`, so one could assume the site change is the reason for removing the link.

The problem with this behavior is: There are privileges on meta sites. Users are able to view votes, retag, vote to close, or protect questions, create tags, as well as edit or delete posts only once they have the equivalent main site privilege.

> [image: Error message on U&L Meta without reputation required for creating new tags]

---

#### The [bug](/questions/tagged/bug):

There is no link to a user's privileges information on meta sites, but his main site privileges apply there as well. **Please add the privileges link.**

#### The [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

**Create a real privileges page for meta sites** that inherits the applicable privileges from the main site (all of them, except possibly chat related), and adds possibly meta-specific privileges.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: @nhinkle I believe you meant to say "It is logical."

Answer (score 1):

#### The [bug](/questions/tagged/bug):

Links across the two sites may confuse new users. This is why the link is not there at the moment and why I'm marking your bug as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

#### The [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

Creating a new set of privilege pages for meta sites is doable, but it's a network-wide request which needs to be discussed on meta-so. I encourage you to discuss it there.

Comment: "*Links across the two sites may confuse new users.*" You waited until the help center was implemented so you could `status-nothingtodo` this? ;-) Also, the *What's meta?* link in *help* links to the main page. So it's not like this isn't broken already.